# Unable to Filter on DJANGO model linked to an already created MySQL View

Tags: django, django-models

I have created a view on a MySQL database based on core tables of the database. I am trying to pull that view into a Django model to ultimately access it and render in a HTML template. This is how the data data View looks like on the MySQL database side (This is from TOAD). This view is rendered from 3 tables.

[image]

When I run the following code to access and validate that the model is actually working on the Django world.

```
 from project.models import model_name
 model_name.objects.first()
```

it is giving me the following error:

```
OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'model_name.id' in 'field list'")
```

it clearly is filtering on a column on the database that does not exist (id is not a column on the view in the database).

This is how the django view looks like (This is an exact replica of the DB view as I created it with inspectdb):

```
class RipAggRepairLeadTime(models.Model):
    a = models.CharField(db_column='col1', max_length=50, db_collation='utf8mb4_general_ci')  # Field name made lowercase.
    b = models.CharField(db_column='col2', max_length=50, db_collation='utf8mb4_general_ci', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    c = models.IntegerField(db_column='col3', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    d = models.DecimalField(db_column='col4', max_digits=28, decimal_places=16, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    e = models.DateTimeField(db_column='col5', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    f = models.IntegerField(db_column='col6', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    g = models.CharField(db_column='col7', max_length=50, db_collation='utf8mb4_general_ci', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    h = models.CharField(db_column='col8', max_length=50, db_collation='utf8mb4_general_ci', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    i = models.CharField(db_column='col9', max_length=256, db_collation='utf8mb4_general_ci', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    j = models.DateTimeField(db_column='col10', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    k = models.DateTimeField(db_column='col11', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    l = models.CharField(db_column='col12', max_length=50, db_collation='utf8mb4_general_ci', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    m = models.CharField(db_column='col13', max_length=256, db_collation='utf8mb4_general_ci', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    m = models.CharField(db_column='col14', max_length=50, db_collation='utf8mb4_general_ci', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    o = models.DateTimeField(db_column='col15', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    p = models.CharField(db_column='col16', max_length=50, db_collation='utf8mb4_general_ci', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    q = models.CharField(db_column='col17', max_length=80, db_collation='utf8_general_ci', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    r = models.FloatField(db_column='col18', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False  # Created from a view. Don't remove.
        db_table = 'db_table_name'
```

I am really struggling with this, I could use all some help.

Why is it filtering along id although it does not exist? There is no primary key in this view.

This is more detail on the error message:
[image]